# Train and predict using SVM theory

Tags: svm

I have implemented character recognition using a library
but I still don't get how SVM theory works in training and prediction process, I just understand SVM is only finding the hyperplane

E.g., suppose I have a training image as follows

---

[image]
**image from google, number zero**

---

How do we find hyperplane for each training data like above?
How is the prediction process is done?
How can the SVM classify the data based on those hyperplane?

Thank you very much if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use opencv and python.Opencv has implemented svm and you can use it by function call.

SVM is machine leraning model for data classification.We can use SVM to classify images.the steps are

1. you must have a training dataset(a dataset of images whose labels are known)
2. Extract features [features are color,shape,hog,surf,sift etc..] from that images and store that,also store the assosiated labels
3. then train svm using these datas
4. Now you can use svm to predict labels of unkonwn images

this [link](http://www.svm-tutorial.com/) will help you

Answer (score 0):

First, It is a non linear separable problem you have to implement kernel SVM which projects them into higher dimensional space where it becomes linearly separable. You can use sklearn library to achieve the above.